# How to get framebuffer image and save it to texture in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to get front-face and back-face of cube and save them to texture for calculating difference of them.

This is what I want to get.

1. Vertices of cube is passed to pipeline for getting front-face of cube and save it to texture
2. Vertices of cube is passed to pipeline for getting back-face of cube and save it to texture
3. Using texture of both front-face and back-face of cube, calculate the difference of them

I have paintGL() like this,

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

  QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
  QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;
  QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;

  cameraTransformation.rotate(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
  cameraTransformation.rotate(beta, 1, 0, 0);

  QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 0, distance);
  QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);
  QVector3D eye = QVector3D(0, 0, 0);

  vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, eye, cameraUpDirection);

  shaderProgram.bind();
  shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix*vMatrix*mMatrix);

  //vertex array enable
  shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
  shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");

  //color array enable
  shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("color", colors.constData());
  shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("color");

/  /glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices.size());

  //vertex&color array disable
  shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");
  shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("color");

  shaderProgram.release();
}
```